# Unable to find the good mySQL provider for EntityFramework 6.2

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I spent a few hours and i'm unable to find the right mySQL provider for Entity Framework 6.2 in Visual Studio 2017.

**Here is my error when tri to use EF :**

[image]

I read severals guide, and no succes :(

**Here is my App.config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Here is my packages.config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.6.5" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MahApps.Metro" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.10.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.10.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**Here is the content of mySQL Installati**on :

[image]

I tried to unistall MySQL connector,mySQL for Visual Studio, Entity Framwork, and i rebuild all the solution, no changes :(

Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html